# How to convert a file into byte array in memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here is my code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
 {
    foreach (var file in files)
        uploaddb(file);   

    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am converting this file into byte array using this code:

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads/Book1.xlsx");
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```

And then I am uploading this code into my nosql database.This is all working fine but the problem is i don't want to save the file. Instead of that i want to directly upload the file into my database. And it can be possible if i can just convert the file into byte array directly without saving it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
        uploaddb(file);   
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

///Code to Convert the file into byte array
}
```

Comment: Um... so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: *file.OpenReadStream()* look for the documentation of IFormFile.OpenReadStream

Comment: When you originally saved the file, what form was it in? However you had it in memory, it should have already been a byte array, or convertible to a byte array. We would need to see how you are obtaining the file in the first place, and how you are saving it.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

As opposed to saving the data as a string (which allocates more memory than needed and might not work if the binary data has null bytes in it), I would recommend an approach more like

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
  if (file.Length > 0)
  {
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      file.CopyTo(ms);
      var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
      string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
      // act on the Base64 data
    }
  }
}
```

Also, for the benefit of others, the source code for `IFormFile` can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/IFormFile.cs)

Comment: you could shorten the code by using the copy functions on IFormFile themselve.

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
        formFile.CopyTo(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
}

Comment: @Bosken85 Good catch!  I updated the example to reflect your recommendations.

Comment: You can also use `file.CopyToAsync(ms)` now.

Comment: Any way I can copy only the first 20 bytes or so to the memory stream and byte array? Only need those to check the file signature

Comment: Something to the effect of the following should help you out. `using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream()) { var buffer = new byte[20]; stream.Read(buffer, 0, 20); }`

Comment: @erdomke why do we need file.CopyTo(ms);?

Comment: @Roxy'pro That line reads the file contents into a MemoryStream (backed by a byte array) so that you can convert the byte array to base64.

Answer (score 58):

You can just write a simple extension:

```
public static class FormFileExtensions
{
    public static async Task<byte[]> GetBytes(this IFormFile formFile)
    {
        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var bytes = await formFile.GetBytes();
var hexString = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: Miss *await* before formFile.GetBytes(); Or Am I Wrong?

Comment: Let's change method name to GetBytesAsync(), so this suffix will indicate this is async function

Comment: @MahmoodGaribov this won't happen as I don't see a point to add the suffix. 
See also: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/5to6/async-suffix#reason-for-no-async-suffix

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to convert it to a byte array:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
   if (file.Length > 0)
    {
      var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
      {
        string contentAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[contentAsString.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(contentAsString.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Run a .jpg through this and see what you get. OP asks for _`byte`_ array.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve your file by using the Request.Form already implemented (as image for instance) :

```
var bytes = new byte[Request.Form.Files.First().Length];
var hexString = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Hope it help